# Installing MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm using [this official guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-the-latest-stable-version-of-mongodb) to install MongoDB on my Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus). At `Run MongoDB Community Edition` I got

> Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

After typing `sudo service mongod start`. I just looked into `/var/log/mongodb`, and it's empty. I didn't have any other error before this problem. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you followed the 4 steps in that page?

Comment: Yes, installing didn't give me any errors

Comment: Once try this http://askubuntu.com/a/770133/564542

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I don't have `mongodb.service` at `/etc/systemd/system` as stated on your link. What should I do now?

Comment: Start reinstalling from the scratch

Comment: Already tried, I don't have the slightest idea about this behavior

Comment: Wait let me give the complete steps as answer, so that it'll be helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131835/discussion-between-gabrielrado-and-jyothi-babu-araja).

Comment: I fail to understand why is this question considered too broad. I ran into same problem and solution by Jyoti Babu worked fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For updates check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition).

**Steps to install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu 16.04**

Run these commands in Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>):

To remove an already installed MongoDB

1. `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`
2. `sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb`

Then start installing with the following commands:

1. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6`
2. `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

To start MongoDB run:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: I don't know how since this are the exactly instructions from official guide, but this worked after I changed my server from `sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade`. I think the problem was related to this, and not mongodb actually. Thanks, anyway!